# Returning multiple rows instead of multiple result sets in a MySQL's Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a slow stored procedure that only moves data arround the database but does not need to return any result. As the process is slow (lots of data on unindexed tables), I want to have progress logs returned as result while the stored procedure is working.

Right now, I'm using this:

```
SET str = CONCAT('Moved ', v_movedmessages, ' messages.');
SELECT str;
```

inside loops, and in more places.
This works, but generates a result set for every time I call Select.

How do I code this to return multiple rows in a single result set, instead of multiple result sets with a single row?

Because of how my stored works, I can't just make a single Select to output the messages, and storing them on a variable to be Selected at the end is not acceptable because it defeats the purpose of being able to have a sense of progress while the stored chunrs the data.

[This is a screenshot of MySQL Workbench to show how are the results displayed right now](http://s17.postimg.org/65l9e4epr/workbench_multiple_results_example.png)
Note: the stored is only called once, but as it returns multiple results, in the output it looks as if it was called multiple times.

Comment: if your procedure generates multiple rows, why not store the result in a temp table and return them at the end?

Comment: because it defeats the purpose of being able to have a sense of progress while the stored chunrs the data.

Comment: In TSQL (Microsoft SQL), you would use `PRINT` for progress messages.  They get returned on a separate stream.